# accessing width of parent div from inside child div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

My problem is this. I have a parent `div` which is `100%`. I have another 3 `divs` of widths as `20%` , `60%` and `20%` which altogether fills the parent `div`. Now my issue is I want to open a view on `button` click. The `button` is implemented in the middle `div` which is `60%` of width. The view I want to open should cover up the whole page. But because my middle `div` is `60%` it only extends as far as 60% leaving other parts of the page blank.

So how can I place the view for `100%` width staying inside the child `div` which is 60%.

This is how I display the view on `click`:

```
return (
      <div className="middle_div">
          <input className='post_data_input' placeholder="Ask your question here" ref="postTxt" onClick={this.popup_ques}/>
             {this.state.showComponent ? <QuestionOverlay/> : null}  
      </div>
);
```

The view i'm displaying on button click

```
render() {    
   return (
       <div id="overlay">          
       </div>    
   )
}

export default QuestionOverlay;
```

**CSS**

parent div

```
.body_clr{

    background-color: #eceff1;
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
```

child div

```
.middle_div{

    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:20%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    position: relative;

}
```

new view

```
#overlay{
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Component that you wants to render on `Button` click, put that in the main `div` like this:

```
return
    <div>
        {this.state.showComponent ? <QuestionOverlay/> : null}
        <div className="first_div"/>    
        <div className="middle_div">
            <input className='post_data_input' placeholder="Ask your question here" ref="postTxt"
                   onClick={this.popup_ques}/>
        </div>
        <div className="last_div"/>
    </div>
```

When you click the `button` it will cover the entire screen.

Answer (score 1):

The best way of having a full-screen-width element within a limited-width parent is to use `position: relative` and set negative margins:

```
#overlay {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin-left: -50vw;
  margin-right: -50vw;
}
```

Hope this helps!